# Multiple Table Joins with Group_Concat where some records don't exist in all tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-concat, concat-ws

I am trying to do a fairly complex (for me) query that will grab a Description field from a Main Table and then append it with titles and values from related Look-Up-Tables. Not all records have records in the Look-up tables. I'll pose further questions as subsequent questions as I go along, but to start my issue is that only those records with values in all the tables show up.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09047/13

- (null)
- This is Record 2 Text
  **Color**:
  Red
  **Fruit**:
  Apple
- (null)

If I use Concat_WS I get all records but my 'label' in the concat disappears:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09047/16

- This is Record 1 Text
  Blue
- This is Record 2 Text
  Red
  Apple
- This is Record 3 Text
  Grape

So my first step is to get all the record descriptions regardless of how many Look-up-Tables they exist in and to get the Names/Labels displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need `COALESCE`:

```
Select J.id, 
  Concat(J.Description,
    COALESCE(Concat('<b>Color</b>:<br>',
         group_concat(F.Name SEPARATOR '<br>')),''),
    '<br>',
    COALESCE(Concat('<b>Fruit</b>:<br>',
         group_concat(F2.Name SEPARATOR '<br>')),'')

  ) AS output
from Main J
Left Join LUT_1 L          On J.ID=L.MainID
Left Join LUT_Names_1 F    On F.ID=L.LUT_NAME_ID
Left Join LUT_2 L2         On J.ID=L2.MainID
Left Join LUT_Names_2 F2   On F2.ID=L2.LUT_NAME_ID
Group by J.ID;
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09047/22/0)**

**EDIT:**

As always for MySQL, the query itself is basing on MySQL extension. If you set it to [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) (default for MySQL 5.7.5 and above):

```
SET sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY;
-- query will return error
```

> J.Description' isn't in GROUP BY

To correct this you will need to use aggregation function on that column like: MAX:

```
SET sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY;

Select J.id, 
Concat(MAX(J.Description),
  COALESCE(Concat('<b>Color</b>:<br>',
         group_concat(F.Name SEPARATOR '<br>')),''),
  '<br>',
  COALESCE(Concat('<b>Fruit</b>:<br>',
         group_concat(F2.Name SEPARATOR '<br>')),'')

)
from Main J
Left Join LUT_1 L          On J.ID=L.MainID
Left Join LUT_Names_1 F    On F.ID=L.LUT_NAME_ID
Left Join LUT_2 L2         On J.ID=L2.MainID
Left Join LUT_Names_2 F2   On F2.ID=L2.LUT_NAME_ID
Group by J.ID;
```

Comment: The Coalese worked well, reviewing above. I was about to post a follow-up question in Stack because, although I cannot seem to replicate with my simple examples I am getting duplicated results e.g. `Fruit</b><br>Apple<br>Banana<br>Grape<br>Apple<br>Banana<br>Grape` and wonder if the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is part of that.

Comment: Hmm ok I did both the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and the `Max(Description` yet I keep getting the dupes. It is always on the second/last LUT.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `concat_ws()` may be throwing off what you want to do.

The following produces the two labels, even when there are no values:

```
Select J.id, 
       Concat(J.Description,
              '<br><br>',
              '<b>Color</b>:<br>',
              coalesce(group_concat(F.Name SEPARATOR '<br>'), ''),
              '<br>',
              '<b>Fruit</b>:<br>',
              coalesce(group_concat(F2.Name SEPARATOR '<br>'), '')
             )
from Main J Left Join
     LUT_1 L
     On J.ID = L.MainID Left Join
     LUT_Names_1 F
     On F.ID = L.LUT_NAME_ID Left Join
     LUT_2 L2
     On J.ID = L2.MainID Left Join
     LUT_Names_2 F2
     On F2.ID = L2.LUT_NAME_ID
Group by J.ID, J.Description;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09047/30) is a SQL Fiddle.

In addition, if you have multiple fruits or colors, you are going to get duplicates.  For this reason, you want the `distinct` keyword (or to pre-aggregate along each dimension).  So the working SQL is more like this:

```
Select J.id, 
       Concat(J.Description,
              '<br><br>',
              '<b>Color</b>:<br>',
              coalesce(group_concat(distinct F.Name SEPARATOR '<br>'), ''),
              '<br>',
              '<b>Fruit</b>:<br>',
              coalesce(group_concat(distinct F2.Name SEPARATOR '<br>'), '')
             )
from Main J Left Join
     LUT_1 L
     On J.ID = L.MainID Left Join
     LUT_Names_1 F
     On F.ID = L.LUT_NAME_ID Left Join
     LUT_2 L2
     On J.ID = L2.MainID Left Join
     LUT_Names_2 F2
     On F2.ID = L2.LUT_NAME_ID
Group by J.ID, J.Description
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b578b1/3) is a SQL Fiddle that illustrates this point.  Just remove the `distinct` and see the difference in the results.

Comment: Great catch as I was just about to post that that was an issue. `Distinct` indeed saved the day, and I did the `Max(Description` recommended by `lad2025` and it works much better now. Still a few steps to go which I will post as separate questions but great help and insights thanks.