# Recursive Parents using Joins and Group_Concats with Main Table and Look-up Tables

Tags: mysql, recursion, group-concat

I am appending the Description Field of a MysQl Table with the Names and Values of various related Lookup Tables (`LUTs`). Not all records have any/all Look-up table values, a problem I have solved with a lot of great help [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348902/multiple-table-joins-with-group-concat-where-some-records-dont-exist-in-all-tab).

My challenge now is that the values on the Look-up tables can have parents and that can in some cases go up a few levels (using a field `ParentID` in each LUT).

I can extract the Parents to one level up using brute force additional joins as in [this SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab89b4/6), yet adding multiple joins for each `LUT` to get possible Parents seems unwieldy. Is there a way to modify the query to 'recursively' grab the parents.

As you can see in the case of e.g. `Plantain` my query finds `Banana` but won't find `Fruit` unless I do yet another join, which means I'd need 3+ joins per table, and this query will have a dozen or more joined tables when all is said and done.